# Hearts in address bar?

Tags: html

I've seen [here](https://github.com/tenderlove/hearts/tree/master/lib) when I click on the file hearts.rb that my address bar contains those hearts even on my phone.

How does this work ? Where to find escaping codes like this one ?

Comment: I see boxes on Google Chrome Windows 7 x64. Might it be platform / browser specific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unicode?

❤ ♥ ♡

https://www.google.com/?q=%E2%9D%A4%20%E2%99%A5%20%E2%99%A1

Actually, after a little searching, the ones in that file name are 0x01f499 through 0x01f49C, which are part of the Emoji Unified codeset, which is supported in iOS.  Not all fonts or browsers support this unicode range.

Comment: I didn't know Unicode codes could be real pictures, thought it was just text... Thank you !